# Python Regular Expression for stopping in between

Tags: python, regex

This is my string:

> age: adult/child  gender: male/female  **age range: 3 - 5 years/5 - 8 years/8 - 12 yrs/12 years and up**  product type: costume  character: animals & insects  material: polyester  theme: animal  age start: 3 years  age end: adult features:  -face is seen through the mouth of the zebra.  -zipper closure in the front and a tail in the back.  -set includes: jumpsuit and head mask.  -animal collection.  age: -adult/child.  gender: -male/female.  age group: -3 - 5 years/5 - 8 years/8 - 12 years/12 yrs and up

I want to catch only the bold part with python regex. But I am not able to do it. I used this regex but not working quite possibly. My Regex is:

```
\bage[a-z]?\b.*\d+\s(?:years[a-z]?|yrs|month[a-z]+)
```

This was getting the weird answer, catching unwanted string.

Comment: Try [`age range:.*?up`](https://regex101.com/r/xC3aD3/1)

Comment: Is it safe to assume that "product type" will always be following your desired string?

Comment: @TheGr8Adakron ... Either you check or comment on the below answers if you are unhappy with them or edit your question with more details.

Comment: @IronFist he looks like never check any answer for all his questions !

Answer (score 0):

You could try this pattern using `re.search()`:

```
import re

string = 'age: adult/child  gender: male/female  age range: 3 - 5 years/5 - 8 years/8 - 12 years/12 years and up  product type: costume  character: animals &amp; insects  material: polyester  theme: animal  age start: 3 years  age end: adult features:  -face is seen through the mouth of the zebra.  -zipper closure in the front and a tail in the back.  -set includes: jumpsuit and head mask.  -animal collection.  age: -adult/child.  gender: -male/female.  age range: -3 - 5 years/5 - 8 years/8 - 12 years/12 years and up'
match = re.search(r'(age range:.*?)  ', string)
if match:
    print(match.group(1))
```

Output:

```
age range: 3 - 5 years/5 - 8 years/8 - 12 years/12 years and up
```

This relies on the assumption that each item of data is separated by *two* spaces as shown in the given string. The pattern says to match the string `age match:` followed by zero or more characters (non-greedy), followed by exactly 2 spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
\bage range:\s*(?:\d+\s*-\s*\d+\s*y(?:ea)?rs/)+\d+\s*y(?:ea)?rs and up\b
```

See [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eK1nM9/1)

Answer (score 0):

If "product type" is always following your desired string, then you can use [lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
>>> r = re.search(r'(age range:.*?)(?= product type)', s)
>>> r.group(1)
'age range: 3 - 5 years/5 - 8 years/8 - 12 years/12 years and up'
```